# Forfiles is not working in batch file but it is working in command line

Tags: batch-file

```
FORFILES -pc:\tempfolder -s -d-6 -m* -c "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE RD /S /Q @FILE"
```

is not working in batch file but it is working in command line

I am using older version of forfiles for windows xp. As mentioned above forfiles is working in command prompt, but when i copy the same command to batch file it's giving can't execute (error 2).

Comment: Are you using a scheduled task or otherwise a limited account to launch the batch file?

Comment: Try this: `FORFILES -p c:\tempfolder -s -d -6 -m * -c "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE RD /S /Q @FILE"`.

Comment: I am the user of a system, I am not admin. I tried the above one-which you gave-is also not working. If this command executes in batch file, i want to schedule it through windows scheduler.My question is when the same command executes in command prompt without any error, it has to execute in batch file also. what's the problem here, why it's not executing?

Comment: The command you posted doesn't work for me, not on batch and not on the command line. The command I posted works on both for me.

Comment: Your posted command not working for me in command prompt and batch file as well. If i execute your command i am getting the following error.   FORFILES v 1.1 - emmanubo@microsoft.com - 4/98 .If you want i can give you the screen shot of error.

Comment: is there any alternative options to do the above task?

Comment: I use forfiles version `5.2.3790.0`. It works also in XP.

Comment: Download latest forfiles.exe [here](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/tips_and_tricks.aspx)

Comment: can this be used to windows 98?

Answer (score 0):

http://web.archive.org/web/20150527024532/http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/tips_and_tricks.aspx

Click Download

Drop Forfiles.exe C:\

C:\forfiles.exe -p "C:\Documents and Settings\test\My Documents\Downloads\Test file" -s -m *.* /C "cmd /c del @path" /d -14

Copy a old computer .exe file in the above location (don't drag it or you lose it forever.)

Change the "-14" to any days with a newer file in the same location, (make sure you copy it) run the batch file.

Now change "-14" to "-1", both files should be gone if you did it correctly.

Now set up a schedule to run it every whatever days for your heart contempts.

wrote this here bc I keep running in here from google and so many sites doesn't say you needed fortfiles.exe program itself for the cmd prompt from seeing any errors.

You can test the file your self and list the files wherever forfile.exe is located in. It is safe to run bc it doesn't have a cmd batch file to delete.

Enjoy!

ps. you can Drop the "forfiles" here "C:\WINDOWS\system32\"
without having to add "C:\forfiles.exe" in the cmd prompt and run it.